# Installed elasticsearch on EC2. Now how to connect it with my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, bitnami

Default search performance on my wordpress site is quite disappointing. So i wanted to have my search box powered by elasticsearch as advised in numerous blogs.

I installed elastic search on my existing t2 micro-instance with the help of bitnami installer & got message "elasticsearch successfully installed", access your application here link. But clicking on that link leads me to a strange interface with menu items - overview, indices, structured query etc.

Even after googling 3 days, I can't find a guide on how to connect this with my my wordpress site. Can someone here please help me.

Comment: Did you try this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/fantastic-elasticsearch/

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. But what to enter in the "Enter elasticsearch server url" field of Fantastic ElasticSearch Plugin Settings? Bitnami sent me this link as elasticsearch access url: http://54.84.201.72/elasticsearch-head/. Is it all I need to do?

Comment: That is the URL to head.  If you take off `elasticsearch-head` it should work.